# Ensuring a dropdown menu overrides all content below with Z-Index

Tags: jquery, html, css, z-index

Been wrestling with some menu/z-index issues. I have set the z-index to be the highest and toggled with relative on and off.

Tried to paste it into a CodePen, but even though the relevant code is in the there. The dropdown isn't working, but you get the idea.

Basically, when you hover over Product Videos the dropdown partly shows but goes behind the jquery banner which loops through the large images.

Any ideas what would allow the menu to always be on top?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dNPdZx

```
#menu {
        height: 80px;
        position: relative;
    }
    #menu {
        background: #515151;
        height: 40px;
        border: 0;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0;
        -moz-border-radius: 0;
        -khtml-border-radius: 0;
        border-radius: 0;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        -moz-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
    #menu {
        background: #585858;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
        height: 37px;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
        -khtml-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
        border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #DDDDDD;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #DDDDDD;
        box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #DDDDDD;
        padding: 0px 5px;
    }

    @media (min-width: 1001px)
    #menu ul {
        -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -webkit-flex-direction: row;
        -ms-flex-direction: row;
        flex-direction: row;
        -webkit-justify-content: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
        justify-content: center;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: table;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
        -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    #menu ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        position: static;
    }

    #menu > ul > li {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 0;
    }

    #menu > ul > li {
        position: static;
        z-index: 0;
    }
    #menu > ul > li {
        padding: 0 5px 0 0;
    }
    #menu > ul > li {
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        z-index: 20;
        padding: 6px 5px 5px 0px;
    }

    a, a:visited, a b, #menu > ul > li > a, #menu > ul > li ul > li > a, ul.box-category > li > a, #footer .column ul li, .category-list ul li, .category-list ul li a.cat-list-name, .product-grid > div, .box-product > div, input, textarea, select, input[type="text"], input[type="password"] {
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
        -o-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
        transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
    }

    #menu > ul > li > a {
        color: #FFFFFF;
        font-weight: bold;
        line-height: 28px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
    #menu > ul > li > a {
        font-size: 13px;
        color: #FFF;
        line-height: 14px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        padding: 6px 10px 6px 10px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        z-index: 6;
        position: relative;
    }

    #menu > ul > li > div {
        z-index: 10;
    }
    #menu > ul > li > div {
        z-index: 10;
    }

    #menu > ul > li > div {
        border: 1px solid #000000;
        background: #E3E3E5;
    }
    #menu > ul > li > div {
        display: none;
        background: #FFFFFF;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 5;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #000000;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
        -khtml-border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
        border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
        background: url(../image/menu.png);
    }

    #menu > ul > li > div > ul {
        vertical-align: top;
        z-index: 9999;
    }
    #menu > ul > li > div > ul {
        display: table-cell;
    }
    @media (min-width: 1001px)
    #menu ul {
        -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -webkit-flex-direction: row;
        -ms-flex-direction: row;
        flex-direction: row;
        -webkit-justify-content: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
        justify-content: center;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: table;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
        -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    #menu ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        position: static;
    }

    #menu > ul > li > div > ul > li {
        position: static;
        z-index: 9999;
    }

    #menu > ul > li > div > ul > li a {
        padding-right: 14px;
        z-index: 9999;
    }
    #menu > ul > li > div > ul > li > a {
        color: #000000;
    }
    #menu > ul > li > div > ul > li > a {
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    a, a:visited, a b, #menu > ul > li > a, #menu > ul > li ul > li > a, ul.box-category > li > a, #footer .column ul li, .category-list ul li, .category-list ul li a.cat-list-name, .product-grid > div, .box-product > div, input, textarea, select, input[type="text"], input[type="password"] {
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
        -o-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
        transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
    }

    #menu > ul > li ul > li > a {
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
        -khtml-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
        border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
        padding: 4px 4px 4px 6px;
    }
    #menu > ul > li ul > li > a {
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 4px;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        display: block;
        white-space: nowrap;
        min-width: 120px;
    }
```

Comment: I'm confused on what's happening here. I don't see any kind of drop down in the codepen demo...

Am I missing something?

Comment: it seems you'd saved you life if you had started your css from scratch

Comment: Try to add some high z-index on #menu element. Also, z-index doesn't work  if element has "position: static"

Comment: I have quite a few categories that aren't in this pen, basiaclly. If Search, has a dropdown. The Product Video text shows through/underneath the dropdown menu